# RPi+RDM6300 Serial port not working

Tags: serial, rfid

I'm trying to use my RDM6300 module with the Raspberry Pi 3 as show on this site: https://behindthesciences.com/electronics/raspberry-pi-rfid-tag-reader/

I disabled the terminal tty by putting in /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1
```

I wired the module to 5V, GND, GPIO 8 and 10 (BCM 14 and 15) but I can't still communicate with the module using the serial port. I'm using this python script

```
import time, serial

sl = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)

while True:
    ID = ""
    read_byte = sl.read()
    if read_byte == "\x02":
        for i in range(12):
            read_byte = sl.read()
            ID = ID + str(read_byte)
        print(ID)
```

and the kernel 4.9.78-v7+

Comment: With linux 4.14.18-v7+ the serial port is now working fine.

Comment: I am having the same issue and tried to follow the answer below with no luck. Did you end up using ttyS0 or serial0? I have linux version > 5. Are there any other configuration issues you found that you needed to change?

Comment: Hi @russelrillema . Honestly, I have no idea. The system was in prod with the same kernel up to few months ago, when was dismissed. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to the see list of peripheral in `ls /dev`?
Have you try `sl = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 9600)`?

Comment: Alright, i can see /dev/serial0 and /dev/serial1 but no one is receiving data from the module (i near the key and nothing is shown either via minicom)

Comment: Do you have invert RX and TX?

Comment: Try to delete `console=serial0,115200` in `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: Yes i tried to invert RX and TX without any result. I have no console=serial0,115200 neither in /boot/config.txt nor in /boot/cmdline.txt . Loopback is working fine (connecting RX and TX togther) and the same module on my Sunfounder mega is working fine too.

Comment: `serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 9600)` worked for me using the python3-serial package